# Trouble trying to skip iteration of a while loop in Java

Tags: java, loops, skip

I'm new to Java (and to programming in general). I have a program that is supposed to run a method on two variable strings, but only if the strings are the same length and are not identical.

I've tried using

```
while(i < n){
    if (string1.length() == string2.length() && string1 != string2){
        compare(string1, string2);
        i++
    }
}
```

but it still runs the *compare* method even if the strings are identical.

I've also tried using

```
while(i < n){
    if (string1.length() == string2.length(){
        if (string1 == string2){
            continue;
        }
        compare(string1, string2);
    }
    i++
}
```

but this also still runs the *compare* method regardless of whether or not the strings are identical.

Is there an issue with my formatting, or perhaps misused keywords? Thanks!

Comment: Try using String equals() method for comparison.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if `compare` will run if strings are really identical (in case using the same value via `string1 = string2`)

Answer (score 1):

This `string1 != string2` does not test `String` value equality, only reference equality. You need `!string1.equals(string2)`. Or your `while` would need to be something like,

```
if (string1.equals(string2)) {
  // ... they're equal.
}
```

It is also worth noting that the two `String`(s) must have the same `length()` or `equals()` would return `false`.

Comment: you are 25 sec faster

Answer (score 0):

Using equals() method instead of ==. Double equal sign can't use in object compare.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (string1.length() == string2.length() && string1 != string2)
```

With

```
if (string1.length() == string2.length() && !string1.equals(string2))
```

`==` check the reference equality. when you come in to `String` variables they have two different reference in the heap while having same `value`. To check the equality of values you should use `equals()`